# KDE: how do i find and switch current global keyboard layout from CLI?

Tags: layout, kde-plasma

I'm on KDE and I need to find out and to be able to switch current global keyboard layout in a script. I've made a research on `setxkbmap` - but in this case it's of no help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
setxkbmap -print | grep xkb_symbols | awk '{print $4}' | awk -F"+" '{print $2}'
```

to find out current layout. The following allows to set it:

```
setxkbmap -layout us
setxkbmap -layout ru
```

and this toggles it:

```
if [ `setxkbmap -print | grep xkb_symbols | awk '{print $4}' | awk -F"+" '{print $2}'` = us ] ;then echo "EN"; echo "changing to RU..."; setxkbmap ru ; else echo "RU"; echo "Changing to US..."; setxkbmap us ; fi
```

If You use gxneur -- it can't cope with all this, but standard Kubuntu layout indicator works fine.

Comment: And it also doesn't cope well with a current layout changing hotkey.

Comment: In Ubuntu 14.04 this doesn't change the Unity layout indicator. Is there a way to solve this?