# get current active keyboard layout(language) in linux

Tags: linux, keyboard-layout

In my C/C++ program I want to know which language is user going to type. I mean the language whose ID is displayed in the corner of the task bar. Like EN or RU or ZH or FR or IT.

I know how to get the list of possible layout:

```
$ setxkbmap -query | grep layout
```

output:

```
layout:     us,ru
```

But how to know which one is selected right now? (for the current window)

Comment: There is a risk that there is no common standard for this. Did you read: http://nabble.documentfoundation.org/Detecting-current-Keyboard-layout-in-English-td4049780.html

Comment: Or maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021111/kde-how-do-i-find-and-switch-current-globar-keyboard-layout-from-cli

Answer (score 10):

`setxkbmap -print` isn't helpful in this case, which was also my first idea. I have found a [little tool](https://github.com/nonpop/xkblayout-state), very easy to compile

```
sudo apt-get install git
mkdir -p `~/src`
cd `~/src`
git clone https://github.com/nonpop/xkblayout-state.git 
cd xkblayout-state
make
```

Now you can run the command `./xkblayout-state` to get the current layout, e.g.

```
./xkblayout-state print "%n"                          
German%
```

or list all installed layouts

```
./xkblayout-state print "%N"
German
English
English
```

<sup>In this case without a trailing `%`. I would have expected that, because I have not added a `\n`.</sup>

Comment: works for me, but I noticed it only shows "system" (RU,EN in my case) languages, ignoring ibus Chinese.

Comment: yes, `print "%s %n"` shows `ru Russian` for Russian, `en English` for English, and `en English` for Chinese.