# Vim mappings depending on keyboard layout

Tags: vim

Is there a way to do certain mappings for specific keyboard layouts?

For example:

```
if iskeyboard('es')
  let mapleader = ","
endif
```

Does vim support this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vim doesn't know anything about the keyboard layout, it just receives a stream of keypresses. That mapping falls into the responsibility of your operating system (which translates the raw, physical keypresses reported by the keyboard driver into logical keys).

Therefore, any solution depends on querying the current layout from the operating system. Vim can interact with it via`:let output = system({command})`. The actual `{command}` depends on the operating system; [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021111/kde-how-do-i-find-and-switch-current-globar-keyboard-layout-from-cli) is an answer for Linux. If that's too complex, maybe you can check the current language (`$LANG` on Linux), or a special environment variable that you set for each system (assuming the layout is fixed for each system).